# Importing third party Libraries into a Stenciljs Project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, stenciljs

So Im trying to import the third party npm module 'rss-parser' to my Stenciljs project. I tried it like in the official documentation:

```
    let Parser = require('rss-parser');
    let parser = new Parser();

    (async () => {

      let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
      console.log(feed.title);

      feed.items.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
      });

    })();
```

I got the Error: `Can't find variable: require`.

I think I'm somehow missing how I need to install these libraries but I can not figure out how. I've red about moudle bundlers but I thought that comes with the Stenciljs compiler already.

Is it a problem that Im trying to import old JS code in a ES6 project?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Stencil components are written in TypeScript, so you use `import` to pull in dependencies:

```
import Parser from 'rss-parser';
```

More on TypeScript's modules here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

var Parser = require('rss-parser') is a requireJS syntax which is not going to work with stencil.
You need to import it using one of the following ways:

```
import Parser from 'rss-parser';

import { Parser } from 'rss-parser';

import 'rss-parser';
```

And this purely depends upon how the module has exported the variable.

Another thing you might need to do in your stencil.config.ts file is to set

```
nodeResolve: true
```